# Non-hex digit used for Unicode escape error when setting org-latex-classes

Tags: latex, debugging, string

When I try to set `org-latex-classes` with the following code:

```
(setq org-latex-classes
      '(("article"
         "
\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
%\usepackage[heading]{CJK}
\usepackage{zhnumber} % package for Chinese formatting of date time (use /zhtoday)
%\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime} % set date time to numeric

% Set default indentation

\setlength\parindent{12pt}

% Set Paper Size, Page Layout (another variable is 'bindingoffset')
\usepackage[margin = 1.5in, paper = a4paper, inner = 2.5cm,
outer = 2.5cm, top = 3cm, bottom = 2.5cm]{geometry}

% Keep paragraph indentation while having a line break in between paragraphs.
\edef\restoreparindent{\parindent=\the\parindent\relax}
\usepackage{parskip}
\restoreparindent

% Indent first paragraph.
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fontspec} % packages for title and section-heading font setting.

% Set Font.
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmainfont{Calibri} % Set serifed font to Calibri. Originally set to 'Times New Roman', but it cannot display certain characters such as ①②③.
\setCJKmainfont{MingLiU}
\setCJKsansfont{Kaiti TC} % Set Chinese font. NOTE: Remember to append CJK before of the font class. CJK HAS to be there for the font to show.

\titleformat*{\section}{\fontsize{16}{18}\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\fontsize{12}{14}\bfseries\sffamily} % Set formats for each heading level. 'sffamily' will point to the sans-serif font. In this case, 「楷體」.
\renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\sffamily} % Set title font.

% Set quotation font.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newCJKfontfamily\quotefont{Kaiti TC}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\quotefont\normalsize}

% Tweak default settings.
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} % Set line width.
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{目次} % Translate content page title to Chinese. (Could possibly be done automatically with '\usepackage[heading]{CJK}'. TODO experiment. )

% For text-boxes

\usepackage{mdframed}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\begin{mdframed}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\end{mdframed}}

% [FIXME] ox-latex 的設計不良導致 hypersetup 必須在這裡插入
\\usepackage{hyperref}
\\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true, %把紅框框移掉改用字體顏色不同來顯示連結
  linkcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  citecolor=[rgb]{0,0.47,0.68},
  filecolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  urlcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  pagebackref=true,
  linktoc=all,}
"
         ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
         ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
         ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
         ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
         ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))
        ))
```

I get this error:

`Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Non-hex digit used for Unicode escape")`

The debugger reveals that the error lies on this line: 
`\usepackage{xeCJK}`

But I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the code. 
A LaTex file containing the same line compiles without any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out what's wrong. Elisp requires a backslash in a string (i.e., between double-quotes `""`) to be escaped in Lisp, so the following code works:

```
(setq org-latex-classes
      '(("article"
         "
\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\\usepackage{xeCJK}
%\\usepackage[heading]{CJK}
\\usepackage{zhnumber} % package for Chinese formatting of date time (use /zhtoday)
%\\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime} % set date time to numeric

% Set default indentation

\\setlength\\parindent{12pt}

% Set Paper Size, Page Layout (another variable is 'bindingoffset')
\\usepackage[margin = 1.5in, paper = a4paper, inner = 2.5cm,
outer = 2.5cm, top = 3cm, bottom = 2.5cm]{geometry}

% Keep paragraph indentation while having a line break in between paragraphs.
\\edef\\restoreparindent{\\parindent=\\the\\parindent\\relax}
\\usepackage{parskip}
\\restoreparindent

% Indent first paragraph.
\\usepackage{indentfirst}

\\usepackage{titlesec}
\\usepackage{titling}
\\usepackage{fontspec} % packages for title and section-heading font setting.

% Set Font.
\\setsansfont{Arial}
\\setmainfont{Calibri} % Set serifed font to Calibri. Originally set to 'Times New Roman', but it cannot display certain characters such as ①②③.
\\setCJKmainfont{MingLiU}
\\setCJKsansfont{Kaiti TC} % Set Chinese font. NOTE: Remember to append CJK before of the font class. CJK HAS to be there for the font to show.

\\titleformat*{\\section}{\\fontsize{16}{18}\\bfseries\\sffamily}
\\titleformat*{\\subsection}{\\fontsize{14}{16}\\bfseries\\sffamily}
\\titleformat*{\\subsubsection}{\\fontsize{12}{14}\\bfseries\\sffamily} % Set formats for each heading level. 'sffamily' will point to the sans-serif font. In this case, 「楷體」.
\\renewcommand{\\maketitlehooka}{\\sffamily} % Set title font.

% Set quotation font.
\\usepackage{etoolbox}
\\newCJKfontfamily\\quotefont{Kaiti TC}
\\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\\quotefont\\normalsize}

% Tweak default settings.
\\renewcommand{\\baselinestretch}{1.2} % Set line width.
\\renewcommand{\\contentsname}{目次} % Translate content page title to Chinese. (Could possibly be done automatically with '\\usepackage[heading]{CJK}'. TODO experiment. )

% For text-boxes

\\usepackage{mdframed}
\\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\\begin{mdframed}}
\\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\\end{mdframed}}

% [FIXME] ox-latex 的設計不良導致 hypersetup 必須在這裡插入
\\usepackage{hyperref}
\\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true, %把紅框框移掉改用字體顏色不同來顯示連結
  linkcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  citecolor=[rgb]{0,0.47,0.68},
  filecolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  urlcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  pagebackref=true,
  linktoc=all,}
"
         ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
         ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
         ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
         ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
         ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))
        ))
```

LaTex itself doesn't need doubled backslashes.

Comment: `C-h i`, Elisp manual, `i backsla TAB`, choose completion `backslash in strings`. That takes you to manual node [Syntax for Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html).